# Methods to restart died process

Tags: python, linux

There's a little app named logivew that I'm writing a script to monitor, along with some other tasks. In the main while loop (which will exit when the app I'm most concerned about closes), I check to see if logview needs restarting. The code I have presently is roughly as follows:

```
#a good old global
logview = "/usr/bin/logview"


#a function that starts logview:
port = 100
log_file = "/foo/bar"
logview_process = subprocess.Popen([logview, log_file, port],
                                 stdout = subprocess.DEVNULL,
                                 stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)

#a separate function that monitors in the background:
while True:
  time.sleep(1)

  logview_status = 0

  try:
    logview_status = psutil.Process(logview_process.pid).status()
  except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
    pass

  if(logview_status == psutil.STATUS_STOPPED or
     logview_status == psutil.STATUS_ZOMBIE or
     logview_status == psutil.STATUS_DEAD or
     logview_status == 0):
    print("Logview died; restarting")

    logview_cli_list = [logview]
    logview_cli_list.extend(logview_process.args)

    logview_process = subprocess.Popen(logview_cli_list,
                                       stdout = subprocess.DEVNULL,
                                       stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)

  if(some_other_condition): break
```

However, if I test-kill logview, the condition triggers and I do see the printed message, but then I see it again, and again, and again. It seems that the condition triggers every single iteration of the loop if logview does die. And, it never does get restarted properly.

So clearly... I'm doing something wrong. =)

Any help (or better methods!) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show us the full test loop?

Comment: Edited for better completeness. =)

Comment: Short form: Use a process supervision system provided by your OS vendor. There's no good reason to reinvent that wheel.

Comment: Almost every modern UNIX will provide one, be it systemd, upstart, or similar.

Comment: Well sure... but surely there's a way to do it in Python, and my above code is the spirit of what I'm shooting for.

Comment: No, doing it "in Python" is the wrong thing, same for doing it "in C" or in any other language. No matter *what* language your code is written in, you should still be using your OS vendor's process supervision system to supervise that code. On an OS using systemd (which includes RHEL7 and newer, modern Arch, modern Debian, and others), that means you create a `.service` file describing how to start your program and drop it in place.

Comment: ...at that point, systemd is responsible for starting your program, tracking its logs, restarting it if it fails (if that's what the service file says to do), etc. And unlike your approach with `psutil`, it does this without polling -- no delays to wait for the next poll, and no overhead from checking whether a process that's still running is active -- by letting your operating system send it a SIGCHLD if and when the process exits.

Comment: Incidentally, this isn't *at all* some newfangled systemd feature -- even 1980s unixes had this kind of functionality built in, though at that point you put the program you wanted to always be running in `/etc/inittab`. (The `/etc/rc.d/init.d` approach is actually *worse* than the inittab approach that preceded it, inasmuch as it doesn't inherently provide supervision... but that's a longer rant).

Comment: (The SIGCHLD+`wait()` approach is also better because a parent process reaping the entry for one of its children from the process table finds out the exit status of that process, or, if it was killed by a signal, which signal it was -- so you can have better logging, or otherwise customized behavior configured based on exactly *how* a supervised process exited; trying to poll from the process table gives you none of that).

Comment: (BTW, a process that's waiting for its parent to reap its process-table entry is exactly what a zombie *is*, so if you implement a process supervision system correctly -- or use an already-existing well-built one -- its child will only be a zombie for the instant between when it exits and when it responds to the signal telling it the child died by calling `wait()` to reap the process-table entry, getting detailed information on how the exit took place).

Comment: ...Yes. I've been using Unix both professionally and personally for a good long while (not the 80's, but the 90's, anyway) and I agree with the principle of your rant. However, your answer(s) don't provide any substantive, actionable material for me. And as noted in the solution below, it was just a typo. There's a handful of reasons I'm not using systemd for this, and that should've been obvious given the fact that the question was about a Python script in the first place. You might've asked, rather than writing all of that. =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your logview program but the problem is here:

```
logview_cli_list = [logview]
logview_cli_list.extend(logview_process.args)
```

When you're creating the argument list, you're putting `logview` twice in your command, because `logview_process.args` also contains the name of the launched command, so the program probably fails immediately because of bad args, and is run again and again...

The fix is then obvious:

```
logview_cli_list = logview_process.args
```

a better fix would be to create the process in the loop if a given flag is set and set the flag at the start.
When process dies, set the flag to trigger the process creation again. Would have avoided this copy/almost paste mistake.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you. =)